# split list in sub lists by number of elements

Tags: python, list, split

In python, if I have the list of elements

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

and a list of numbers

```
n = [2, 1, 3]
```

How I can split the list `l` by the numbers in `n` ?

And get this list of lists

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `islice`:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> n = [2, 1, 3]
>>> it = iter(l)
>>> out = [list(islice(it, size)) for size in n]
>>> out
[['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit obfuscated, but still:

```
ll = [[l.pop(0) for _ in range(k)] for k in n]
```

Note that this traversal will not leave the list intact because of the `pop()` thingy.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an iterator out of the list. Then call `next` the appropriate number of times.

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> n = [2, 1, 3]
>>> it = iter(l)
>>> [[next(it) for i in xrange(k)] for k in n]
[['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
  n = [2, 1, 3]

  result = []
  for i in n:
    j = l[:i]
    result.append(j)
    l = l[i:]

  print result
```

Gives

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

It's not as short as some other solutions, but it sure as hell is readable

Answer (score 1):

```
cuts = [sum(n[:i]) for i in range(len(n) + 1)]
>>> [l[cuts[i]:cuts[i + 1]] for i in range(len(cuts) - 1)]
[['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

This leaves the list intact:

```
>>> l
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: Doesnt give the desired output though

Comment: The desired output is returned by the top portion.  >>> [l[cuts[i]:cuts[i + 1]] for i in range(len(cuts) - 1)]
[['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be most optimized as it will only required `len(n)` number of iterations.

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
n = [2, 1, 3]

res = []
temp = 0
for i in n:
    res.append(l[temp:temp+i])
    temp = temp+i
print res
```

Returns:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.split` :

```
>>> np.split(l,[sum(n[:i]) for i in range(len(n))])
[array([], dtype=float64), array(['a', 'b'], 
      dtype='|S1'), array(['c'], 
      dtype='|S1'), array(['d', 'e', 'f'], 
      dtype='|S1')]
```